# Which is the better location to compress images? In the browser or on the server?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, image-compression

I have a Django project and i allow users to upload images. I don't want to limit image upload size for users. But want to compress the image after they select and store them. I want to understand which is better:

1. Compress using java-script on the browser.
2. Back end server using python libraries.

Also it will be helpful if links can be provided to implement the better approach.

Comment: What image file formats do you want to support? If you only accept PNG, JPEG, and GIF you don't need to do any compression, since they are already compressed.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to compress on the browser in order to :

- avoid loading the server with many CPU and RAM heavy consuming calculations (as numerous as number of clients)
- dwindle bandwith needed when transfert image threw the network

Answer (score 1):

I would compress in nginx (or apache) since this is the right place to do it. no need for python libraries to do this

small example:

```
gzip  on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_min_length 1400;
gzip_types  image/png image/gif image/jpeg
```

more on it --> [in the nginx docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/)